# Check if document.location matches a certain pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Say, I'd like the condition to be true if the document.location equals `http://www.example.com` or `http://www.example.com/example/anythinghere/`, but FALSE if the location does not fit exactly, for example `http://www.example.com/example/anythinghere/sdjfdfasdfaf` will return FALSE.

Naturally, I'd write something like:

```
if(document.location == "http://www.example.com/" || 
    document.location == "http://www.example.com/example/*/")
```

However, I know the good ol' asterisk wildcard won't work, and, as an amateur with regex, I can't manage to find the proper setup to look for an exact match to the pattern. What would you suggest for the second half of the conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 if(document.location == "http://www.example.com/" || 
/^http:\/\/www.example.com\/example\/[^\/]+\/?$/.test(document.location))
```

The will test if your URL matches `http://www.example.com/` exactly, or if it uses a regular expression to see if it matches `http://www.example.com/example/ANYTHING_HERE_EXCEPT_FORWARD-SLASH/`.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sD7cC6)

Comment: For some reason, it's not returning a match. I don't know if I mentioned it, but the final slash is apparently optional. I tried with and without, though, and nothing.

Comment: @JTApps If the final forward slash `/` is optional then put a `?` at the end of the regex pattern like this: `/http:\/\/www.example.com\/example\/[^\/]+\/?/`.

Comment: @JTApps I have edited the expression a bit and added a demo link, please check.

Comment: Still not matching. I'm running `/^http:\/\/www.example.com\/test\/[^\/]+\/?$/.test(window.location.href‌)` and window.location.href is `http://www.example.com/test/somethinghere`

Comment: @JTApps It won't work because the URL contains the word `test` right after `http://www.example.com/test` which you said didn't want to accept.

Comment: I changed the word `example` to `test` in the code, if you look in the regex.

Comment: @JTApps Sorry for that. Anyway I have tested your modification in my demo link and it worked fine just like you want.

Comment: @JTApps Your final expression would have worked without a slash at the end with a little modification: /^http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/(?:example\/[^\/]+\/?)?$/.

Comment: `/^http:\/\/www\.reddit\.com\/(?:r\/[^\/]+\/?)?$/` I deleted my comment because I realized I could fix it thanks to what you mentioned before. This is what I came up with, and and it works and matches yours! Thanks for your help, especially with the learning process.

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression should do it:

```
/^http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/(?:example\/[^\/]+\/)?$/
```

That's the starting part of `http://www.example.com/`, followed by an optional `/example/somecharacters/`.

Usage:

```
var re = /^http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/(?:example\/[^\/]+\/)?$/;

if(re.test(document.location.href) {

}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DrUze/)

Answer (score 1):

Try matching using:

```
regex = /^http:\/\/www.example.com\/(?:example\/(?:[^\/]+\/)?)?$/
```

Specifically this says:

- Start at the actual start of the string
- Match http://www.example.com/
- Matched as an optional group (optionally, because of the training ?):

  - Match example/
  - Matched as an optional further group:

    - A string of at least 1 char, containing no forward slashes
    - Followed by a single forward slash
- Followed by the end of the string

If you then apply this I think it covers all your cases:

```
regex.exec("http://www.example.com/example/anythinghere/") // matches
regex.exec("http://www.example.com/example/anythinghere") // doesn't match (no trailing slash)
regex.exec("http://www.example.com/example/anythinghere/qwe") // doesn't match (extra end chars)
regex.exec("http://www.example.com/exam") // doesn't match (no subdir)
regex.exec("http://www.example.com/") // matches
```

Answer (score 0):

try a regex that only acepts letters, like `[a-zA-Z]+`, otherwise `http://www.example.com/example/;:ª*P=)#/")#/` will be valid

`http://www.example.com/example/qwerty/uiop/` will be valid too? ends with `/` but have two middle levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookahead based regex:

```
m = location.href.matches(/www\.example\.com\/(?=example\/)/i);
```